# При обновлении на MacOS 10.14.3 тормозит картинка в картинке

Tags: google-chrome, macos

Смотрю постоянно видео в режиме "картинка в картинке" через Chrome на MacBook Pro late 2015. До обновления на 10.14.3 все работало хорошо, после обновления сама "картинка в картинке" тормозит. Открыл через Safari, то же самое. При этом, включается охлаждение, чего ранее не было. Помогите, откатываться назад, или что-то делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С новым обновлением проблема исчезла